# How to add column based on specific row differences?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in the following format:

```
DT <- data.table(
id=c("123", "123", "125", "125", "123", "123", "123"), 
action=c("started", "finished", "started", "finished", "started", "started", "finished"), time=c(as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:24:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:29:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:34:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 08:24:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 09:45:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 10:33:00")))
```

```
    id  action      time
1   123 started     2014-02-19 03:24:00
2   123 finished    2014-02-19 03:29:00
3   125 started     2014-02-19 03:30:00
4   125 finished    2014-02-19 03:34:00
5   123 started     2014-02-19 08:24:00
6   123 started     2014-02-19 09:45:00
7   123 finished    2014-02-19 10:33:00
```

I would like to add a column that shows the time differences (action: "finished"-"started") between the rows per id. The table is sorted by time, but it is possible that there is missing data (e.g. it might happen that a "finished"-action is missing as it is the case in rows 5 and 6. In this case row 5 should be ignored and the difference between 6 and 7 is calculated. The final table should look like this.

```
    id  action      time                   durationInMinutes
1   123 started     2014-02-19 03:24:00    NA
2   123 finished    2014-02-19 03:29:00    5
3   125 started     2014-02-19 03:30:00    NA
4   125 finished    2014-02-19 03:34:00    4
5   123 started     2014-02-19 08:24:00    NA
6   123 started     2014-02-19 09:45:00    NA
7   123 finished    2014-02-19 10:33:00    48
```

Is there a data.table solution for that?

Comment: Do the `id` values repeat as in your example? Or is there only supposed to be one `started`/`finished` pair per `id` value?

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. id values may repeat. It is like a user starting an application and ending it multiple times. I need the differences for each of the "sessions". However, some events might be missing, meaning there can be two consecutive started or finished-actions. With consecutive started-actions, only the last one should be used. With consecutive finished-actions only the first one can be used and the others must be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

```
DT[, duration := as.integer(time[action == "finished"] -
                            tail(time[action == "started"], 1))
   , by = cumsum(c(0, tail(lag(id) != id, -1)))][
     action == "started", duration := NA]
DT
#    id   action                time duration
#1: 123  started 2014-02-19 03:24:00       NA
#2: 123 finished 2014-02-19 03:29:00        5
#3: 125  started 2014-02-19 03:30:00       NA
#4: 125 finished 2014-02-19 03:34:00        4
#5: 123  started 2014-02-19 08:24:00       NA
#6: 123  started 2014-02-19 09:45:00       NA
#7: 123 finished 2014-02-19 10:33:00       48
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for my late reply. I made an additional comment to my question above. Ids can repeat - it is like a user having multiple sessions.

Comment: @Miriam see the edit - it's just a matter of adjusting the `by` to suit your needs

Comment: I see, thanks. However, when I apply the edit, I get the following "duration" column and not the one that you posted above:c(NA,-371,NA,-376, NA, NA,-376). Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Miriam really? copy-pasting the data from OP? If yes, then I'd try manually checking what `as.integer(DT$time[2] - DT$time[1])` is and take it from there.

Comment: `as.integer(DT$time[2] - DT$time[1])` gives the correct result: 5

Comment: @Miriam not sure what to tell you - copy-pasting OP the above is what I get (R 3.0.1, data.table 1.8.11).

Comment: I got R3.0.2, data.table 1.8.10. Strange, but thanks for your effort!